# CSS Selected State

Tags: css

What CSS code should i put in my style.css so that the menu font becomes black and bold when in selected state.

```
<li class="selected"><a href="/health-coaching.html">Health Coaching</a></li>
```

HELP! thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

```
.selected a:active
{
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

To apply same settings when hovering over, use this:

```
.selected a:hover
    {
        color: black;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
.selected a {
    color: #000;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use This

```
li.selected a {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000;
}
```